# Zend autloading different namespaces from the same directory?

Tags: php, zend-framework, namespaces, autoload, bootstrapping

I have a models directory in my project, and I would like to save/files classes there with different namespaces.
Example:

```
models/User.php with classname Model_User
models/Table_User.php with classname Model_Table_User
```

For the first namespace I have this in bootstrap.php

```
$resourceLoader->addResourceTypes(array(
    'model' => array(
    'namespace' => 'Model',
    'path' => 'models'
    )
));
```

I can't figure out how to add the second namespace so it detects files starting with `Table_` Any ideas?

For now I've added a second directory named 'tables' but it's getting confusing because I have each model name twice (once in the models diretory and once in the tables directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's something I do myself.
I have "Model_" sat in '{APPLICATION_PATH}/models/' and "DbTable_" sat in '{APPLICATION_PATH}/models/dbtables/'.

```
$resourceLoader->addResourceTypes(array(
    'model' => array(
    'namespace' => 'Model_',
    'path' => APPLICATION_PATH.'/models/'
    ),
    'dbtable' => array(
    'namespace' => 'DbTable_',
    'path' => APPLICATION_PATH.'/models/dbtables/'
));
```

You should of course modify this to according to your classnames and folder structure.
APPLICATION_PATH is defined in your index.php -- but I don't remember if it contains a trailing slash, so check that just in case. (I'm not on my pc at the moment so I cannot check...)

Simple as that! :)

Comment: But I'd still need to use the same filename twice with this example right? That what's annoying me the most, duplicate filenames can be confusing... Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: You might have duplicate file names (eg. User.php) but the path would be different. It's not a bad practice. Have you ever checked the insides of ZF? It's full of abstract classes in "Abstract.php" files.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the _ in Table_User. The autoloader is probably looking for:

```
models/Table/User.php
```

Try renaming the file to

```
TableUser.php
```

And the class to:

```
Model_TableUser
```

Or create the `Table` folder and put User.php in there.