# Where's the best place to store application specific non-model classes in a Zend Framework app?

Tags: zend-framework, architecture

Given that the model is a "domain-specific representation of the data upon which the application operates." [[Wikipedia: MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller)], service, form, plugin classes, etc. aren't considered part of the model, so they go in their own directories under `/application`. The default resource auto-loader sets this up for us, so `MyApp_Form_Login` is automatically found in `/application/form/Login.php`.

For my application I need to write a custom authentication adapter. The logic in it will be application-specific, so it's not reusable library code, therefore it doesn't belong in `/library/MyApp`. It's not a service class, so it doesn't belong in `/application/service`, nor a form, etc. So, idiomatically, where should this class be stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create additional folders in your `application` folder and add a resource path in your `Bootstrap` class.

For example, assuming that you use a namespace for all your application-specific classes (models, forms, plugins, etc) of 'Application', you could use the following:

```
protected function _initAutoloader()
{
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH,
            'namespace' => 'Application',
        ));
    $autoloader->addResourceType('MyType', APPLICATION_PATH . '/mytypes');
    return $autoloader;
}
```

Then you could have a class named `Application_MyType_Foo` stored in the file `application/mytypes/Foo.php`.

If you look at the code for `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader`, that's essentially what they do to give you autoloading for the models, forms, plugins, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just create an application specific library. Usually such a class is not the only candidate for a personal library.

Comment: Surely it doesn't belong in the library because it isn't reusable across different applications. It will depend upon application-specific configuration options being set and available in the registry (and therefore depend upon there being a registry available). It seems weird to me to have two-way dependencies between application code and library code.

Comment: The is the reason I call it "application library" ;) Its library, specific to your application. You will see other classes later, for that you will not find an applicable module, or subdirectory. However: Inject the options into your objects upon instanciation (or maybe later), instead of the other way. Your classes are not testable this way. The registry as "data container" is bad style anyway.

Comment: Yep, dependency injection is the way to go, I was just illustrating an example. I still find the idea of creating a library for this type of class weird. What makes plugins, for example, so special that they get a dir in `/application` but an auth adapter doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to create a service class (we know where these live: `/application/service`) that encapsulates the application-specific authentication logic. It can use a library class to do basic auth, e.g. check username and password against a DB, but then also apply application-specific logic before returning the result to the client code.

Example:

```
class MyApp_Service_User {
  public function authenticate($sUsername, $sPassword) {
    $oAuth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $oAuthAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(...);
    $oResult = $oAuth->authenticate($oAuthAdapter);

    /* Application-specific logic */

    return $oAppSpecificAuthResult;
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently answered a similar question, have a look at the link below and see if this helps! ;)

[Zend autloading different namespaces from the same directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513968/zend-autloading-different-namespaces-from-the-same-directory/4533375#4533375)